# Scriptaculous Drag and Drop

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Basically i am dragging certain elements to many droppable areas. Once i have dragged all my respective elements i wish to save these drag conditions and update a database using php. But for the purpose of understanding how to do it i have one droparea in my example here.

The drag and drop works. I just cant get it to do anything.
for example

```
$A($('ee').getElementsByTagName('div')).each(function(item) {
     new Draggable(
        item,

        {revert: true,});

        });

 Droppables.add(
 'droparea',
 {
    hoverclass: 'hoverActive',
    accept:'g',
    onDrop: moveItem
 }
```

);

function moveItem( drag,drop){

```
drag.parentNode.removeChild(drag);
drop.appendChild(drag);
}
```

I want to once i drop the elements into the droparea i can the press save and "do" something in the php script.

```
<DIV id ='ee'><?foreach($player1 as $player_id => $playername){?><tr><td><div id ="player_<?=$player_id?>" class = 'g'><?=$playername?></div></td></tr>
```

Take it that droparea is only a normal at the minute.

```
<div id = "droparea"></div>
```

Once i drag and drop $pname i want to send that to a php script but dont know how??? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your dropbox within a POST form and then have some hidden fields accompanying each item in your draggable items loop with the required value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="players[]" value="PLAYER_ID_HERE">
```

Then once they're within the dropbox and within the form area, hit submit and it should go through as a normal POST array.

$players = $_POST['players];